# Ubuntu Ocaml llvm unbound module ExecutionEngine

Tags: ubuntu, ocaml, ocamlbuild

I have been working through the LLVM Kaleidoscope Tutorial for OCaml. On the third part of the tutorial, I have navigated to the example code in the folder

```
OCaml-Kaleidoscope\Chapter4
```

I am encountering an issue when compiling with

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind toy.byte -package llvm -package llvm.executionengine
```

on VirtualBox Ubuntu.

The error I am getting is

```
File "toplevel.ml", line 37, characters 25-53:
Error: Unbound module ExecutionEngine
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that llvm changed a lot between version 3.4 and 3.7. You can find the old library [here](http://llvm.moe/ocaml-3.4/Llvm_executionengine.ExecutionEngine.html) while the new is [here](http://llvm.moe/ocaml-3.7/Llvm_executionengine.html).

I've never use llvm before so my solution is not be the better/good one. Well in fact there is even a bug : I don't manage to get anonym function, so I name them, but I can't manage to have several function, only the first one is took into account... But here is a general idea, that anyone can improve, and someone that know llvm a little bit better would certainly find the error. Stop speaking, let's code :

First, install the deps :

```
opam install ctypes ctypes-foreign llvm
```

Then, because of the ExecutionEngine module rewrite, I changed the definition of `let result = ExecutionEngine.run_function the_function [||]` by (in `toplevel.ml`)

```
open Ctypes
open PosixTypes
open Foreign

[...]

let my_name = "my_function_name" in (* If a name has already been add, value_name the_function should contains it. You should be able to use anonyme functions but I don't manage to get them work *)
let address = get_function_address my_name (funptr (void @-> returning double)) the_execution_engine in
print_string "Evaluated to ";
print_float (address);
```

You need also to update `toy.ml` :

```
let main () =
  ignore (initialize ()); (* Change the initialize *)

  [...]

  (* Create the JIT. *)
  let the_execution_engine = create Codegen.the_module in

  [...]

  (* Set up the optimizer pipeline.  Start with registering info about how the
  * target lays out data structures. *)
  DataLayout.add_to_pass_manager the_fpm (data_layout the_execution_engine); (* Change also this line *)
```

Now you can run the program :

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind toy.byte -package llvm -package llvm.executionengine && ./toy.byte
```

And use it :

```
ready> 43+15;
parsed a top-level expr
----

define double @__my_anom_fct__0() {
entry:
  ret double 5.800000e+01
}

Evaluated to 58.
ready>
```

However, there is an anoying bug : if you try again you get an error. It's like if the function isn't register the second time, but since it's the first time I use llvm somebody else may find easily the error :

```
ready> 1+42;
parsed a top-level expr
----

define double @__my_anom_fct__1() {
entry:
  ret double 4.300000e+01
}

Fatal error: exception Llvm_executionengine.Error("Function __my_anom_fct__1 not found")
```

You can find the example on this fork : https://github.com/tobiasBora/llvm.

Hope it can help, and sorry for the bug.

Comment: When I do this I get the following error: `File "toplevel.ml", line 43, characters 24-33:
Error: This expression has type unit -> float
       but an expression was expected of type float
Command exited with code 2.` Perhaps the edit in toplevel.ml needs adjustment.